# Tuxguitar's player mute

Tags: tuxguitar

I'm trying to get Tuxguitar to play a tab. Player>Start does read the tab, but no sound coming out. Xporting to a mid file and playing through timidity does work, though.

Based on [these guidelines](http://www.tuxguitar.com.ar/tgwiki/doku.php?id=doc:tuxguitar_sound), I did `$sudo apt-get install tuxguitar-alsa`. It then does appear in the list of plugins of Tuxguitar, but still no sound. Also shown below, Tools>Settings>Sound

Any suggestion?

Linux Mint 19.3
TuxGuitar 1.2

[image: Play] 
[image: list of plugins]
[image: Tools>Settings>Sound]